# How to convert a JSON string to a Map<String, Set<String>> with Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am aware of the implementation which converts JSON string to a `Map<String, String>` through :

```
public <T1, T2> HashMap<T1, T2> getMapFromJson(String json, Class<T1> keyClazz, Class<T2> valueClazz) throws TMMIDConversionException {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
        HashMap<T1, T2> map = mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class, keyClazz, valueClazz));
        return map;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}
```

But I cannot extend it to convert my JSON to a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. The above method fails, obviously, as it breaks the Set items and puts in the list. Need some help here!! Thanks

Sample JSON String is as below. This JSOn has to converted to a `Map<String, Set<CustomClass>>`.

```
{
    "0": [
        {
            "cid": 100,
            "itemId": 0,
            "position": 0
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "cid": 100,
            "itemId": 1,
            "position": 0
        }
    ],
    "7": [
        {
            "cid": 100,
            "itemId": 7,
            "position": -1
        },
        {
            "cid": 140625,
            "itemId": 7,
            "position": 1
        }
    ],
    "8": [
        {
            "cid": 100,
            "itemId": 8,
            "position": 0
        }
    ],
    "9": [
        {
            "cid": 100,
            "itemId": 9,
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON would help...

Comment: I have added a sample JSON. Thanks.

Comment: And how would that map to a `Multimap`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
JavaType setType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(Set.class, CustomClass.class);
JavaType stringType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(String.class);
JavaType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, stringType, setType);

String outputJson = mapper.readValue(json, mapType)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `Class` really can not express generic types; so if your value type is generic (like `Set<String>`), you need to pass `JavaType` instead. And that can be used to construct structured `JavaType` instances as well.